Patach read as kholam!
This is a grammatical/ pronunciation question that I'd appreciate to get help with.
Sometimes patach is read as kholam. Example: writen as vayashav read as vayashouv[Bereshit 37,29]. Can anyone explain for me whats the gramatical law behind this. Ty

Are you confusing patach and kamatz?

You’re confusing Kamatz with Patach. This specific type of Kamatz is called a “Kamatz Kattan”. It’s technically a completely different vowel from the “normal” Kamatz, called “Kamatz Gadol”.

The verse quoted is Bereshis 37:29-30: the requested word is
וַיָּ֤שׇׁב
with kamatz under ש. The kamatz does not have stress, and is known as kamatz katan, or a short vershion of kholam in the Babylonian pronunciation adopted by sephardim. It's "o" as dog/fog for Brittish and or/oil/own for American speakers.

It’s 37:29 (or 30), and version has no h

Thanks. Corrected.

The Palestinian pronunciation, not the Babylonian one. The Babylonian pronunciation is what Yemenite vowels are based on.

In America, “dog” and “fog” have a more open vowel, close to “a”. A better comparison for Americans would be “or”, “oil”, “own”, or any other word with “o” followed by a semi-consonant.

Even better is just not assuming everyone here is American

Y DI, are you saying that if there is a kamatz under shin in the beginning of a word, it is always read az kholam?

@Angie the rule is that if a kamatz does not have stress in the word, then it is read as a short cholam, so is chataf-kamatz (even shorter). The place of unstressed kamatz can be anywhere in the word, beginning, middle, end. Tikkun Korin Simanim has a special sign for it (slightly bigger kamatz). https://judaicaplaza.com/products/17802696?_pos=1&_sid=aa8c74e43&_ss=r
